# Botframework error when saving state

Tags: c#, botframework, messenger

In bot framework, when i try to save state, then run the bot from fb messenger I get the error "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue."

On commenting the following line, this error doesn't come anymore:

`await botClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, botData);`

Why could this be happening?
I tried setPrivateConversationDataAsync as well, it gives the same behaviour

Comment: Can you add ApplicationInsights and get the exception details? Looks like an error like 412 Precondition failed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-general-problems#what-causes-an-error-with-http-status-code-412-precondition-failed-or-http-status-code-409-conflict)

Comment: Another resource to look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default state client (`activity.GetStateClient().BotSate`) should not be used within the context of a dialog.  Bot Builder dialogs automatically load state when message processing begins, and persist state when message processing completes.  Instead, use the **IDialogContext** methods to manipulate state within the dialog: `context.UserData.SetValue("UserDataKey", objectToPersist);`